# PHP and Phpmyadmin multiplication

Tags: php, multiplication

I want to hit 2 values with the same id on PhpMyAdmin. According to the codes below, only the aggregation is running in the outputs I receive. I get a value of 0 when I multiply instead of adding.

```
<?php 

$a = 0; 

$oran = new sorgu; 
$k_id = $kuponlar->veri->id; 

$oran->select("*","matches","kid=$k_id"); 
while($oran->verioku()){
    $a =  $a+ floatval($oran->veri->oran);
}

echo $a; 

?>
```

**Screenshots:**

It is necessary to multiply the "oran" values in there. But those with the same "kid" value are at least struck for that table.
[image: It is necessary to multiply the "rate" values in there. But those with the same "kid" value are at least struck for that table.]

That's the code that's running
[image: That's the code that's running]

**Action Required:**

1,25 x 1,5 x 1,3 x 1,55

Comment: Where is the question?

Comment: How do we multiply the "oran" values of the same "kid" values?

Comment: as far as I know, there is no standard function in mysql to calculate the product as an aggregate. also, this has absolutely nothing to do with phpmyadmin.